# Add XML Nodes to specific Node in XmlDocument

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have two XmlDocuments that both have a namespace attribute specified. Both documents have the same structure, but contain different data. I can't seem to get a specific node tree from one document added to the end of the same node tree in a second document. Here is an example of my two documents:

Document #1:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rootnode xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.com/Service/2012-06-18">
    <node0>
    </node0>
    <node1>
        <Item>
            <Id>1</Id>
            ....
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>2</Id>
            ....
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>3</Id>
            ....
        </Item>
    </node1>
</rootnode>
```

Document #2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rootnode xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.com/Service/2012-06-18">
    <node0>
    </node0>
    <node1>
        <Item>
            <Id>4</Id>
            ....
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>5</Id>
            ....
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>6</Id>
            ....
        </Item>
    </node1>
</rootnode>
```

What I'm wanting to accomplish:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rootnode xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.com/Service/2012-06-18">
    <node0>
    </node0>
    <node1>
        <Item>
            <Id>1</Id>
            ....
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>2</Id>
            ....
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>3</Id>
            ....
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>4</Id>
            ....
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>5</Id>
            ....
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>6</Id>
            ....
        </Item>
    </node1>
</rootnode>
```

I'm trying to add all `<Item>` nodes from one document to the other while maintaining the structure of all other nodes. There are an arbitrary number of `<Item>` nodes in either of the documents. Each `<Item>` node has a deep nested number of nodes that describe the Item.

```
Dim dstdoc As XmlDocument = myobject1.XmlDocument
Dim srcdoc As XmlDocument = myobject2.XmlDocument

Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(New NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.mynamespace.com/Service/2012-06-18")

Dim xpath As String = "ns:rootnode/ns:node1//ns:Item"

Dim copiedNode As XmlNode = dstdoc.ImportNode( _
                            srcdoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath, nsmgr), True)
dstdoc.DocumentElement().AppendChild(copiedNode)
```

I certainly know this is wrong... I've tried several different approaches. This particular approach adds all `<Item>` nodes to the destination document, but it adds them to the very bottom of the document instead of after the last `<Item>`.

Could someone please show me how to add a specific node tree an XmlDocument to a specific position in another document? Again, there is a namespace involved and the `<Item>` nodes have nested nodes/elements under each one.

NOTE: The `<Id>` nodes have example data to show uniqueness only. I can never count on any kind of numbering. The order of each `<Item>` node is totally unimportant. I'm just assuming it will be easiest to add additional `<Item>` nodes after the last one in the destination document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.  This line is incorrect:

```
dstdoc.DocumentElement().AppendChild(copiedNode)
```

That is explicitly saying that you want to append to the "document element" (meaning root element).  If you want to append to a particular element in the destination document, you'll first have to get a reference to that target element:

```
Dim destElement As XmlNode = dstdoc.SelectSingleNode("ns:rootnode/ns:node1", nsmgr)
For Each sourceNode in srcdoc.SelectNodes(xpath, nsmgr)
    Dim imported As XmlNode = dstdoc.ImportNode(sourceNode, True)
    destElement.AppendChild(imported)
Next
```

Comment: within the For/Next loop, I get "The node to be inserted is from a different document context." when `destElement.AppendChild(imported)` is excuted. I can see by your code that you have me on the right track. I understand what I was doing wrong now. Can you make sense of this error? Thank you!!

Comment: I'm sorry Jacob, your code worked. The problem was on my end. Hey, thank you again.